# 401 unauthorized from Twitter API with oauth gem in Ruby

Tags: ruby, oauth, twitter-oauth

This is my first experience working with Twitter API's.
I am using the following tools:

- ruby 2.2.0p0 (2014-12-25 revision 49005) [x86_64-linux]
- gem 'oauth'

  - oauth (0.5.1)
  - oauth2 (1.1.0)
  - omniauth-oauth2 (1.4.0)

I obtained a key and secret from Twitter.

I copied and pasted from the [example on Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/single-user) for Ruby.

```
=begin
code taken directly from the example at 
https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/single-user
=end

require 'oauth'
consumer_key, \
  consumer_secret = [
    'CONSUMER_KEY', 
    'CONSUMER_SECRET'
].map { |key| ENV[key] }
raise "Some key undefined." unless [consumer_key, consumer_secret].all?

# Exchange your oauth_token and oauth_token_secret for an AccessToken instance.
def prepare_access_token(oauth_token, oauth_token_secret)
    consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new("APIKey", "APISecret", { :site => "https://api.twitter.com", :scheme => :header })

    # now create the access token object from passed values
    token_hash = { :oauth_token => oauth_token, :oauth_token_secret => oauth_token_secret }
    access_token = OAuth::AccessToken.from_hash(consumer, token_hash )

    return access_token
end

# Exchange our oauth_token and oauth_token secret for the AccessToken instance.
access_token = prepare_access_token(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
p access_token

# use the access token as an agent to get the home timeline
response = access_token.request(:get, "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json")
p response

=begin   

|| #<OAuth::AccessToken:0x000000021ed938 
@token="redacted", @secret="redacted", 
@consumer=#<OAuth::Consumer:0x000000021edb68 
@key="APIKey", 
@secret="APISecret", @options={:signature_method=>"HMAC-SHA1", 
:request_token_path=>"/oauth/request_token", 
:authorize_path=>"/oauth/authorize", 
:access_token_path=>"/oauth/access_token", 
:proxy=>nil, :scheme=>:header, 
:http_method=>:post, :oauth_version=>"1.0", 
:site=>"https://api.twitter.com"}>, 
@params={:oauth_token=>"redacted", :oauth_token_secret=>"redacted"}>
|| #<Net::HTTPUnauthorized 401 Authorization Required readbody=true>
=end
```

What I tried:

- Getting a new key and secret.

  Result:

  > Net::HTTPUnauthorized 401 Authorization Required readbody=true
- Synchronized my server's time because many Stack Overflow posts mentioned that a 401 is returned if the server time varies beyond a certain point. I installed ntp.
- suggestions from [this list](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/FAQ)

  - set the Callback URL in Twitter settings: http://127.0.0.1:3000/auth/twitter/callback
- [API Console Tool](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/tools/console) on Twitter. After authenticating with my Twitter account https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json returns

  > HTTP/1.1 200 OK

  along with expected data.
- checked to see if [Twitter API operating normally](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/status)

Suggestions of where to go from here appreciated.

**UPDATE** [OAuth Tool on Twitter Developer](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/tools/signature-generator/12389783) returns the expected result with a curl execution:

```
curl --get 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json' --header 'Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="redacted", oauth_nonce="redacted", oauth_signature="redacted", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1463742270", oauth_token="redacted", oauth_version="1.0"' --verbose
```

**Expected data is returned.**

> [{"created_at":"Fri May 20 11:05:21 +0000
>   2016","id":733614584754515968,"id_str":
>   "733614584754515968","text":"Three Skills Every New Programmer Should
>   Learn https://t.       co/1p9AxO5JPg via
>   @sitepointdotcom","truncated":false,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"symbols"
>   (truncated)…

Answer (score -1, accepted):

On this line, you should replace "APIKey" and "APISecret" with what you pulled from the CONSUMER_* environment variables.

```
consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new("APIKey", "APISecret", { :site => "https://api.twitter.com", :scheme => :header })
```

The example code from Twitter works fine for me. The wrong consumer keys will give you 401 for sure.

Comment: Thank you! Too much of this was unfamiliar to me to realize what was going on. I appreciate the help!